# UIPickerView width constraint issue

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I need to add UIPickerView to UIAlertController. I use code:

```
let alertView = UIAlertController()
let pickerView = UIPickerView()
pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

alertView.view.addSubview(pickerView)
pickerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertView.view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
pickerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertView.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
pickerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertView.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
pickerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertView.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

present(alertView, animated: true)
```

Here it is a result:

[image]

Why width of the UIPickerView more than UIAlertController?

Also I tried:

```
pickerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertView.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
```

But got the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you give a constraint of width which exactly doing right.Issue is from your side look below image when you give a width constant of alertview.view which one UIalertController's main view.For better understand look below image(last view behind blue colour view colour and PickerView color is red.).

[image]

Now,we show actual alerview which one subview of main view(in above image Blue colour with Ok button).
change width constraint with subview instead of main view like:-

For better under standing:-

```
for view in alertView.view.subviews {
        print(view)
       //just add color which is shown in bellow image.
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
```

So, Solution is like:-

```
pickerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertView.view.subviews[0].widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Result:-

[image]

I hope this help you,
Thanks